# Why does svn status show modified when I haven't changed any files?

Tags: svn

SVN status for some reason shows:

```
 M      .
```

That means that the current directory is modified. But why? I had created a directory named .git inside the main svn repo.

I then added git to the ignore list:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

But it still shows:

```
 M      .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ignore a folder/file, the parent folder is marked as modified until the next commit, but it does not change the status of its children. I think you should try to commit the parent folder (..) . The modifications on .git will be committed, then ignored.

By the way, how this project is under two versioning systems ?

Comment: Thanks. You are right.

Our client uses SVN. I have a team of devs working with git. We use a git repo where we commit to, then from time to time merge with SVN. This is the least pain : ).

Answer (score 2):

It can also be the case that you merged trunk or any other and forgot to commit afterwards -

In my case `svn diff` showed:

```
--- .   (revision 2723)
+++ .   (working copy)

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /trunk/CrowdRoamingV2:r2667-2722
```

You can see that th now holds the merge info in that branch.